# Calling synchronized from non synchronized method ISSUE

Tags: java, multithreading

Why the following code does not guarantee the uniqueness of total_home number among multiple threads even when the logic is in a synchronized block.

```
class Country {
    private static int home = 0;
    int total_home;

    private static synchronized int counter() {
        return ++home ;
    }

    public void getTotal() {
        total_home = counter(); System.out.println(total_home);

    }
}

public class T1 extends Thread {

private Country c;

public T1(Country c) {
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        c.getTotal();
}
```

}

```
public class T2 extends Thread {

private Country c;

public T2(Country c) {
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        c.getTotal();
}
```

}

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Country c = new Country();
    T1 ok = new T1(c);
    T2 ok1 = new T2(c);
    ok.start();
    ok1.start();
}
```

}

This is a program sample.Try to run it 5-10 times and you will see that the value of total_home is not unique every time.

Comment: `synchronized` only guarantees a happens-before order. The value of `home`, however, may still be cached. Try adding `volatile` to `static private int home = 0;`. --- How did you determine that the current approach does not work? Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. --- Two remarks: general consensus is is that the visibility modifier should come before the `static`, and volatile shold come last, so it should be `private static volatile int home = 0;` -

Comment: We do not need `synchornized` when we use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of an `int`.

Comment: @Turing85 I created two threads sharing the same Country objects. Executed them in a loop and saw that the values were not unique each time

Comment: @Turing85 - happens-before _means_ that your first comment cannot be correct. if line A happens-before line B as per the JMM, then B cannot observe any state as it was before line A modified it. `volatile` wouldn't fix anything. Their problem is that they're re-using the same Country object.

Comment: @rzwitserloot not entirely. The unlock of the monitor used by the `synchronized` keywords synchronizes-with (and thus happens-before) the (all) subsequent lock(s). The same statement does not hold true,  however, for the static field since it is not `volatile`. Making the field `volatile` and the method `synchronized` leads to the statement that a write to the `volatile` field synchronizes-with (and thus happens-before) the (all) subsequent write(s) to that field. My initial comment was not precise; I should have clarified that I meant the monitor locks & unlocks, not the write to the field.

Comment: huh. Funnily enough, I get the "correct" result without `synchronized`. @rzwitserloot is there a part of the JLS I am missing wrt. synchronization of bodies of a `synchronized` method? Or does it work "by accident"?

Comment: You mean: No synchronized, no volatile, absolutely nothing of note? The problem with the JMM is: It gives the JVM the freedom to use caches but it doesn't demand that the JVM does so. Hence the 'evil coin' (my term, not the JMM's term) effect: Any code with broken synchronization has behaviour that depends on the results of an evil coin flip. Evil in the sense that it's not reliably random either: It works all day today, and then tomorrow it fails. Or it works on one machine and fails on a nearly identical one, etc.

Comment: @Turing85 the one and only relevant aspect is happens-before. The JMM defines line A as 'happening before' B for various constructs; in this case, it is impossible to witness the state of the world from line B as it was before A ran. (so, if A does `x++`, line B can't witness x prior to the increment). The exiting of a sync block happens-before another thread's entering a sync block.

Comment: @Turing85 _all_ interaction with that field in OP's question occurs within a synchronized block. Given the Happens-Before rule for sync blocks, that means you're fully in the clear. the JMM guarantees you can't run into problems here. A tricky aspect is if some code reads (never changes) that field from outside a synchronized block. That is _not_ actually safe (but on a lot of hardware you won't see it fail. Point is, a JVM impl is free to make that code break, so the code is still broken. Just not in a way that you can ever see until you buy a new computer. Ouch).

Comment: @rzwitserloot Sorry to bother again. Do you have a hard source on the part with the synchronized blocks? I cannot really explain why it works with "only" `synchronized` blcoks since the reads and writes on `home` do not have a happens-before edge according to [JLS, §17.4.4 and §17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4). Those paragraphs only talk about monitor locks/unlocks and write/reads to synchronized fields, but nothing on what happens in a synchronized block

Comment: @Turing85 The `synchronized` _is_ what 'monitor' is about. So, you have HB relationships between monitorexit en monitorenter. You can `javap` some code with a `synchronized` block, this will show you the MONITOR bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has:

> ```java
> Country c = new Country();
>    T1 ok = new T1(c);
>    T2 ok1 = new T2(c);
>    ok.start();
>    ok1.start();
> ```

Which should make it obvious: Count the amount of times `new Country` is executed in your code. It's.. **once**.

Hence, trivially, there is only one Country object available. Both you first and second thread are referring to it. (It's analogous to: They both have a unique address book. But the books contain the same address. All object variables in java are references).

Your synchronized code isn't the problem, that's working fine - every call to `counter()` is returning a unique value.

But, you have 2 threads all invoking `getTotal()` on the exact same single Country object you made.

`ok.c` and `ok2.c` are identical (they refer to the same object). Hence, they of course have the same value for `total_home` - there is only one `total_home` in the system and you overwrite it every time.

There's more in this code that indicates you need to do some more review on how java works. For example, `class T1` and `class T2` are entirely identical - so why do you have these?

Here's what you intended to write, I think:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Country c1 = new Country();
  Country c2 = new Country();
  T1 ok1 = new T1(c1);
  T1 ok2 = new T1(c2);
  ok1.start();
  ok2.start();
  System.out.println("These are guaranteed different: " + c1.total_home + " " + t2.total_home);
}
```

NB: There's currently an upvoted comment that suggests that your `static int home` variable 'might be' cached and that you should add `volatile` to it. **This is incorrect** - `synchronized` is more than enough to eliminate all race conditions. However, `AtomicInteger` is a better option here - `synchronized` is a fairly 'expensive' measure, AtomicInteger gives you a guaranteed unique counter using significantly 'faster' primitives (it doesn't use locks, it uses your CPU's Compare-And-Set (CAS) infrastructure, which is orders of magnitude faster).

Comment: Class T1 and T2 are just a sample. Even though there is only one total_home but I am printing the value after calling the synchronized method.

Please explain @rzwitserloot

Comment: Ran your code on various platforms. [A] it _never_ generated duplicates, and [B] As per the JMM, any JVM implementation that gives you duplicates is broken.